# Fields not visible in Kibana

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

Although my fields are visible in the discover tab, I can't make any kind of visualization with them and i got this message:

> No results displayed because all values equal 0.

This is the data in the discover tab:
[image: Discover Tab]

Visualise data result:
[image: result]

```
**index mappings:*


 {
      "mapping": {
        "httpbeat": {
          "_meta": {
            "version": "5.2.1"
              },
    ..........
      "response": {
                  .....
                "headers": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                    "Content-Type": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 1024
                    },
                    "Date": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 1024
                    },
                    "X-Application-Context": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 1024
                    }
                  }
                },
                "jsonBody": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                    "classes": {
                      "type": "long"
                    },
                    "classes_loaded": {
                      "type": "long"
                    },
                    "classes_unloaded": {
                      "type": "long"
                    },
                    "counter_status_200_health": {
                      "type": "long"
                    },
                    "counter_status_200_login": {
                      "type": "long"
                    },
                    "counter_status_200_metrics": {
                      "type": "long"
                    },
                    "counter_status_302_unmapped": {
                      "type": "long"
                    },
                    "gauge_response_health": {
                      "type": "long"
                    }, ..}
```

any help please?

Kibana  index pattern : 
[image]

PS: The JSON code of the mapping is not completed due to the post rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, the error message indicates that there is nothing shown regarding your aggregation, metric, time range etc. Therefore, even though documents exist on elasticsearch, they cannot be drawn on a visualisation. In order to solve the issue:

- select the aggregation method considering field data type
- set a suitable metric along with the right time range which returns some result

Comment: My problems, that I can't apply any kind of filters in some specific fields, although I can do that for others, which is weird !!  even in the discover tab, those fields exist but I can't play with them!  I 'm following  this  tutorial and there is a  guy  who has  the same  issue too !  [link](https://aboullaite.me/spring-boot-elastic-kibana/)

Comment: even when I'm trying to write this as a filter in the discover section, there is no data shown:**response.jsonBody.heap_committed exists**  although  i have a  displayed  data  as  you see  in the above  picture

Comment: Can you please take a screenshot of your index pattern from Kibana > Management > Index Patterns > Your Index, and share here?

Comment: it seems that I have to flat Elasticsearch nested JSON documents ,cause the nested fields are not supported with kibana : Response

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a visualisation based on data with nested objects. If so, I am afraid, this type of aggregation is not available on Kibana. However, I have found an open issue on GitHub regarding the topic which may provide more information and potential workarounds: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084

Answer (score 0):

[Solution] 
I found a solution for that, in fact httpbeat 5.6.x cannot work with kibana , only  httpbeat v4.1.0 is supported ! so to visualize data you have to change the version of httpbeat (the other version give  nested json documents and  the nested fields are not supported with kibana )